# How to upload file with JS/Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, input, file-upload, puppeteer

I'm trying to figure out how to upload a picture file into an input dialog. It isn't possible to just type in the name and hit enter as I don't see a way in order to automate that with Puppeteer. I figure I will have to set some value as the picture but I'm not sure how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: While the issue is on Puppeteer, if you get the similar issue on Playwright you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132097/

Answer (score 35):

You upload a file by using [`elementHandle.uploadFile`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#elementhandleuploadfilefilepaths).

**Code Sample**

```js
const elementHandle = await page.$("input[type=file]");
await elementHandle.uploadFile('path/to/file');
await page.click('selector-of-submit-button');  // might not be necessary
```

Depending on whether the page directly react to the change of the element, you might need to click a button to submit the form.

Answer (score 11):

After few days of suffering that's works for me:

```
import path from 'path';

const filePath = path.relative(process.cwd(), __dirname + filepath);
await element.uploadFile(filePath);
await element.evaluate(upload => upload.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true })));
```

based on this incredible answer from GitHub:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/857#issuecomment-386222936

Comment: Bro, you are my hero i spend two days on this and alltough through all information my own mixup and a lot of trial and error with ChatGPT finally your code brought it home... !  here is my section const filePath = 'C:\\Users\\maName\\Desktop\\backup\\THePage\\SomeMore\\inc.jpg';
    const elementHandle = await page.$("input[type=file]");
    await elementHandle.uploadFile(filePath);
    await elementHandle.evaluate(upload => upload.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true })));

Answer (score 4):

Here is the way you can use for yourself, but in typescript:

```
const uploadImage = async (
  imagePath: string,
  fileChooserTriggerXpath: string
) => {
  const p = getPage() // this return puppeteer page 
  const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
    p?.waitForFileChooser(),
    clickXpath(fileChooserTriggerXpath),
  ])

  await fileChooser?.accept([imagePath])
}
```