# Automatic file uploading via drag and drop interface from PC to a website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, drag-and-drop

I need to upload a picture from PC to a website that uses drag and drop interface. I am using Javascript to open the necessary link, set properties and click to the upload field. But then a file manager pops up with a window where I need to choose a file from my filesystem. I cannot use Javascript here anymore. How can I automatize this? Somehow I need to upload a picture and then click send button using javascript.
P.S. I am not trying to implement drag and drop box, I need to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Puppeteer`](https://pptr.dev/) to simulate headless chrome and run your automation script

[How to upload file with JS/Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273294/how-to-upload-file-with-js-puppeteer)

Answer (score 1):

Use a user script for example with Tampermonkey:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo

Bind to the `change` event on the file input on your site of interest. Once it's fired, use DOM's `HTMLElement::click()` function to submit your upload automatically